# Angular crear un formulario de login para acceder a una api rest en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, angular, api, angular6

He desarrollado una API rest con laravel 5.8 usando passport , al uso lo que hago es primero hago una llamada donde me autentico y la api en caso correcto me devuelve el token.

Ahora quiero hacer un frontal , ya que hasta el momento solo he desarrollado el backend , y tengo dos dudas muy básicas.

En el frontal no he encontrado un claro ejemplo para acceder a una api rest con laravel.
La segunda duda es , una vez loggeado debo guardar el token en sesión? Ya que en cada llamada hacia la api debo enviarlo verdad? En angular esto como se "llama" no lo encuentro haciendo busquedas en google porque no se como "buscar" este proceso.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acceder a una API RESTful en Angular es muy sencillo ya que puedes, incluso, realizar peticiones HTTP con dos simples líneas de código, mediante el HTTP Client de Angular.

Ahora, dado que tú quieres enviar tu token, tienes 2 opciones:

1. Crear un **HTTP Interceptor** para enviar tu token en los headers del request.

**Pros:**
Te ahorras la molestia de hacerlo manualmente, además tu código será más entendible. Es, seguramente, la mejor práctica.

**Contras:**
Si necesitas interactuar con más de 1 API mediante el HTTP Client de Angular, tu token será enviado a todas las URLs a las que hagas un request. Esto se puede solucionar fácilmente para enviar un token distinto (o no) a cada endpoint.

2. Incluir los headers manualmente en **cada request** que hagas a tu API RESTful.

**Pros: **
Tendrás más control sobre qué envías a cada URL.

**Contras: **
Tu código será menos mantenible, además que se verá estéticamente feo y entre más endpoints tengas, repetirás más código.

**Solución**
Supongamos que tu API se encuentra en *http://mi-api.com* y tu endpoint de login es *http://mi-api.com/login*,

En tu proyecto de frontend (Angular) necesitas inyectar el HTTP Client de Angular (voy a ejemplificarlo con Angular 6, que es la última versión que utilizo actualmente).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(
        public http: HttpClient
    ) { }


    doLogin() {
        const endpoint = 'http://mi-api.com/login';
        const data = {
            username: 'miusuario',
            password: '123456'
        };

        // En este ejemplo voy a usar promesas, pero puedes utilizar Observables si prefieres.
        this.http.post(endpoint, data)
            .toPromise()
            .then(token => {
                // La variable 'result' dependerá de lo que tú envíes desde tu API, siempre y cuando el estátus de la respuesta no sea de error. Yo supondré que result es tu token.
                console.log(result);
                sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                alert('Ocurrió un error al iniciar sesión');
            });
    }

}
```

Ahora, para enviar el token en tu request, tendrás que decidir si quieres hacer un Token Interceptor o agregarlo manualmente a tu request.

**Forma 1: Manualmente**
Una vez que ya tienes el token, deberás enviarlo en tu request (sólo ilustraré una función que hace un request a un endpoint cualquiera, yo usualmente utilizo .NET con OAuth, pero puedes adaptar agregar el header que necesites, o de la forma en que lo envías con Postman):

```
getData() {
    const endpoint = 'http://mi-api.com/login';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'));

    this.http.get(endpoint, { headers: headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Petición exitosa', result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                // Unauthorized, quiere decir que tu token: o no es válido o no fue enviado de forma correcta.
            } else {
                // Otro error ocurrió.
            }
        });
}
```

**Forma 2: Mediante un Interceptor**
Tienes que crear un nuevo archivo .ts, por ejemplo yo le puse *token.interceptor.ts*.

Dentro de ese archivo pega el siguiente código

```
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';

import {
    Observable,
    throwError,
} from 'rxjs';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }

    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler,
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getitem('token')
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(catchError(err => {
                return throwError(err);
        }))
    }
}
```

Ahora, en tu *app.module.ts* necesitas indicar que vas a utilizar un HTTP Interceptor en cada request que hagas con el HTTP Client.

```
import {
    HttpClientModule,
    HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './helpers/token.interceptor';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [HttpClientModule],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: TokenInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    schemas: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Si decides utilizar la **Forma 2**, cada request llevará incluído tu token almacenado en sessionStorage. Además, tus requests se verán de la siguiente manera:

```
getData() {
    const endpoint = 'http://mi-api.com/login';

    this.http.get(endpoint)
        .toPromise()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Petición exitosa', result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                // Unauthorized, quiere decir que tu token: o no es válido o no fue enviado de forma correcta.
            } else {
                // Otro error ocurrió.
            }
        });
}
```

Espero que mi respuesta pueda ayudarte.